# javascript condition for session storage not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, session-storage

Currently working on session storage where user have to select one radio button from the first page and click next button div has to show in the second page in the first page i have created a function with set of objects where the data will be stored using set item in the second i am trying to get those value using get item.

I have two scenarios

1. When the user select pg radio button from the first radio group and if any location like alain / abudhabi **if user select alain | abudhabi from the location** from location then user slect DIP EDU if user click submit button then  in the second page i need to get one check box and create application button the rest should be hide -- **With my code this was working**
2. If the user select ug radio button from the first radio group and if any location like alain / abudhabi  if user click submit button then in the second page I need to get Just a Pay button **but this was not working kindly help me**

Here is my [plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/0Zh3bcJUgB5oGCwakWO4?p=preview) just like fiddle

This is what my code for to get the item from the first page

```
function storedata(){
    var storeDate = {};
    storeDate['storedValue1'] = $('input[id=pg]:checked').val();
    storeDate['storedValue2'] = $('#alain').prop('checked'),$('#abudhabi').prop('checked');
    storeDate['storedValue3'] = $('#slt_mjrpg option:selected').val("Dip - Prof. PG Dip in Teaching");

    sessionStorage.setItem('storeDate', JSON.stringify(storeDate));

}

function storedata1(){
    var storeDate1 = {};
    storeDate1['storedValuej'] = $('#slt_mjr option:selected').val("Bachelor of Arts in Persian").text();
    sessionStorage.setItem('storeDate1', JSON.stringify(storeDate1));
    console.log(storeDate1);

}
```

When i checked in session storage I am getting the storedValue2 as false

[image]

After providing or in this line

```
storeDate['storedValue2'] = $('#alain').prop('checked') || $('#abudhabi').prop('checked');
```

I am getting true in the storedValue2 = true but my output was not working as expected

[image]

In the second page

```
var otherObj = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('storeDate'));
var otherObj1 = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('storeDate1'));
if (otherObj.storedValue1 && otherObj.storedValue2 && otherObj.storedValue3 != "pg") {
    $(".pay_check,.pay_click").show();
    $(".pay_trans").hide();
} else if (otherObj1.storedValuej === "BAP") {
    $('.create_btn,.no_applica').show();
    $('.pay_btn').hide();
} else { * * // I have tried using like this but no use**
    //$('.create_btn,.no_applica,.pay_click').hide();
    $('.pay_btn').show();
}
```

any suggestion guys for the question

Kindly please guide me where I am doing wrong. Thanks in advance

Comment: [Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/1qmcqaso/9/) your special code request :)

Comment: @PDKnight thank you so much you have rocked :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so you have a number of problems here. Mostly due to a misunderstanding of functions.

First of all, we can change

```
storeDate['storedValue1'] = $('input[id=pg]:checked').val();
// to
storeDate['storedValue1'] = $('#pg').val();
```

The `$` function provided by jQuery selects elements based on a given selector. So `$('#pg')` selects the element with the id `pg`. Then `val()` returns the value of the element.

Secondly, we need to change

```
storeDate['storedValue2'] = $('#alain').prop('checked'),$('#abudhabi').prop('checked');
// to
storeDate['storedValue2'] = $('#alain').prop('checked') || $('#abudhabi').prop('checked');
```

You're just misunderstanding boolean operators here. `a || b` resolves to `true` if `a` *or* `b` resolves to true.

And finally the worst offender

```
storeDate['storedValue3'] = $('#slt_mjrpg option:selected').val("Dip - Prof. PG Dip in Teaching");
// to
storeDate['storedValue3'] = $('#slt_mjrpg).val();
```

`val` returns the value of an element. In the case of a select, it will return the value of the *selected option*. Providing a string parameter will *set* the value. So what we're doing instead is just getting the value, and we'll check the value *later*.

In your hide/show function, we don't need to change very much. We're just going to move that inappropriate `val` parameter down here in an equality operation to get a boolean value.

```
if (otherObj.storedValue1 && otherObj.storedValue2 && otherObj.storedValue3 === "Dip - Prof. PG Dip in Teaching")
```

Answer (score -2):

i think session storage is working with only one page.

You should try localstorage instade of sessionstorage.

Try this

```
function storedata(){
    var storeDate = {};
    storeDate['storedValue1'] = $('input[id=pg]:checked').val();
    storeDate['storedValue2'] = $('input[id=alain]:checked').val();
    storeDate['storedValue3'] = $('#slt_mjrpg option:selected').val("Dip - Prof. PG Dip in Teaching");

    localStorage.setItem('storeDate', JSON.stringify(storeDate));

}
```

and

```
var otherObj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('storeDate'));         
        var otherObj1 = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('storeDate1')); 
        if (otherObj.storedValue1 && otherObj.storedValue2 && otherObj.storedValue3 !="pg") {   
            $(".pay_check,.pay_click").show();  
            $(".pay_trans").hide();
        } else if (otherObj1.storedValuej === "BAP"){   
            $('.create_btn,.no_applica').show();
            $('.pay_btn').hide();               
        } else {
**// I have tried using like this but no use**
            //$('.create_btn,.no_applica,.pay_click').hide();
            $('.pay_btn').show();       
        }
```

Comment: sorry not understanding.

Comment: I have tried using local storage in local storage we have two issue 1)  once the page was closed then if i open the new page still the local storage data was available 2) I have already tried using local storage it was not working as expected